# Renumber table rows with a recursive statement

Tags: sqlite, infinite-loop, recursive-query

To understand the behaviour of recursion (in SQLite), I tried the following statements to re-number the rows of a table with a recursive statement:

Let's create a sample table,

```
CREATE TABLE tb
    (x TEXT(1) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO tb
    VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c');
```

and re-number the rows starting from, say, 2 via

```
SELECT tb.x as x, tb.rowid + 1 as idx from tb; 
/* yields expected:
a|2
b|3
c|4
*/
```

Attempting to do the same with a recursive `WITH` (neglecting `ROWID`), results in divergence — here, I have added `LIMIT 6` to prevent the divergence:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
newtb AS (
   SELECT tb.x, 2 AS idx FROM tb
   UNION ALL
   SELECT tb.x, newtb.idx + 1
      FROM tb, newtb
      LIMIT 6 -- only to prevent divergence!
)
SELECT * FROM newtb;
/* yields indefinitely:
a|2
b|2
c|2
a|3
b|3
c|3
...
*/
```

Why does the recursion does not stop when it reaches the end of table `tb`? Could this be prevented?

Note that the problem can be reformulated as how to produce the result of the following procedural pseudo-code in SQLite (without too much ado):

```
tb := {'a', 'b', 'c'};
num := {1, 2, 3};
result := {};  # initialize an empty table

for i in {1, ..., length(tb)}  # assume index starts from 1
    append tuple(num[i], tb[i]) to result;
end for

# result will be {(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')}
```

This is equivalent to the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) operation in a language like Python.

According to a hint by @CPerkins, one can achieve this goal via [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) (for SQLite >= 3.25) very elegantly; eg.,

```
SELECT (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY x)) + 2 AS newId, x FROM tb;
```

Comment: The first problem is that join with no keywords--only a list of tables--produces the Cartesian product of the two source tables.  In other words, `FROM tb, newtb` is the reason that you're getting repeated combinations over all records.  This is true not just within a recursive statement, but that is how any such join is applied.

Comment: next, if you don't have a LIMIT clause, then you need a WHERE clause to actually stop the recursion.  That's why without the LIMIT 6 you would get an indefinite number of rows.

Comment: A recursive cte stops when the recursive part doesn't return any rows; yours always will return one every time.

Comment: Also treating `rowid` as a sequential row number is a mistake, as the former isn't always going to be sequential.

Comment: Window functions would be better for renumbering rows.

Comment: @CPerkins: Could you please provide an minimal example for renumbering rows via window functions?

Comment: @AlQuemist  No.  I was simply giving a comment as an alternative, but your question here is about doing it with recursive statements.  It is not appropriate to keep adding more questions and moving the target of the question.  You would need to ask another question or look for an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the recursion does not stop when it reaches the end of table tb?

Because that's the way it is designed to be and it is extremely useful. It is little different from most languages that have some form of recursion and is often and efficient and effective the way to resolve some programming issues such as traversing a directory tree.

- > Most computer programming languages support recursion by allowing a
  >   function to call itself from within its own code. Some functional
  >   programming languages do not define any looping constructs but rely
  >   solely on recursion to repeatedly call code. Computability theory
  >   proves that these recursive-only languages are Turing complete; they
  >   are as computationally powerful as Turing complete imperative
  >   languages, meaning they can solve the same kinds of problems as
  >   imperative languages even without iterative control structures such as
  >   while and for.[Recursion (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

If you used LIMIT (SELECT count() FROM tb) instead of LIMIT 6 then the recursion would stop based upon the number of rows in the table.

However, if you are looking to renumber (by adding 1 to the rowid) then you would be looking at something more like :-

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
    cte(idx,newidx) AS (
        SELECT (SELECT max(rowid) FROM tb),(SELECT max(rowid) FROM tb) +1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        idx-1, newidx-1 FROM cte
        WHERE idx > 0
    )
SELECT (SELECT x FROM tb WHERE tb.rowid = cte.idx) AS x, newidx, idx AS original FROM cte WHERE x IS NOT NULL;
```

This would (assuming that tb had rows with a, b and c .... X, Y and Z and that rows d-w had been deleted) result in :-

[image]

SQlite's reasoning is :-

> Recursive common table expressions provide the ability to do
>   hierarchical or recursive queries of trees and graphs, a capability
>   that is not otherwise available in the SQL language.
>   [SQL As Understood By SQLite - WITH clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html)
>
> Could this be prevented?

Yes, you can not use recursion as there may be alternatives but as with recursion throughout other languages if you do use recursion then you have to have some means of detecting when the recursion should finish. The use of a WHERE or LIMIT clause facilitates this.

Comment: What happens if table `tb` has no `ROWID`?
I am looking for a simple (recursive) strategy to re-number the rows without using `ROWID`.

Comment: @AlQuemist With the exception of rarely used [WITHOUT ROWID tables](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) and [VIRTUAL tables](https://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) every table has a [**rowid column**](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html). What other number were you going to renumber the table only has a single column which does not a have numeric value?

Comment: I added a note for further clarification of my aim.